# Datatime dando erro python

Tags: python

`mg_time = str(datetime.strptime((datetime.now()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + mg_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')) + timedelta(minutes=timeframe)[11:-3]`

Sou novo em python e não sei muito o que fazer estou meio perdido com esse erro já mudei algumas coisas mas nada vai parece.
**Bom no caso esse programa tinha que funcionar como um catalogador de Velas na IQ Option porém quando ele começa a carregar para catalogar ele da o erro eu queria que ele executasse me mostrando quantidade de velas verdes e velas vermelhas que dão frequentemente em um determinado tempo que eu coloco no link do github tem o código e o vídeo que eu usei para fazer o codigo**
link do código completo do git:
[]- https://github.com/mr-diogo/iqteste/blob/main/iq.py
Isso é para funcionar para catalogar as velas da IQOption mas ele chega nesse erro de datetime e eu não sei o que fazer

```
File "c:\Users\Diogo\Desktop\iq\botzin.py", line 101, in <module>
    mg_time = str(datetime.strptime((datetime.now()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + mg_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')) + timedelta(minutes=timeframe)[11:-3]
  File "C:\Users\Diogo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\Diogo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '2022-03-08 2022-02-25' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: separe essa linha em varias e vc achara o erro com mais facilidade

Comment: @EltonNunes https://prnt.sc/iB0nBWr4NoaM fiz isso não sei se esta certo o erro ficou na linha 102

Comment: mg_time =
mg_time2 = (datetime.now())
mg_time2 = mg_time2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ')
mg_time2 = datetime.strptime(mg_time2 + mg_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
mg_time2 = str(mg_time2) + timedelta(minutes=timeframe)[11:-3]   #um pouco dificil ajudar, mas por em linha é isso que, então vc vai testando linha a linha ate achar o erro, mg_time é uma icognita, em sua duvida vc não fala de onde vem tal valor

Comment: fiz uma sugestão no git, divir uma unica linha em varias e testar separadamente cada linha para achar o erro

Comment: Então o erro ficou na linha 107 que na modificação no git é a linha 104 que da o erro

Comment: @EltonNunes, o período de tempo de 10 dias ficou certo mas agora pelo menos sabe a onde o erro ta exatamente https://prnt.sc/gSeFUDGGzCJr

Comment: o problema é que vc tem 'ano-mes-dia ano-mes-dia' sendo convertido para 'ano-mes-dia hora:minutos', a informação que ta chegando não bate, se o problema é na linha 101, vc separa em linhas e ve onde esta o problema, para ajudar mais, qual é o valor de mg_time na linha 92?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ZkSmM8puS2gL , eu troquei todos para %H:%M e agora o erro mudou para 
´´´
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 2022-03-08 17:55

Comment: @EltonNunes horario = datetime.fromtimestamp(velas['from']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') tem esse valor

Comment: oq quero dizer é vc colocar um print na linha 92, para mostrar o valor que gm_time esta recebendo, eu não tenho acesso ao seu dataframe para testar aqui

Comment: o horario retorna isso https://prnt.sc/vP0cxu-FDHR-

Comment: @EltonNunes Fiquei fazendo teste e vi que tirando essa linha de código ele funciona o porém é que ele não pega o tempo determinado dos dias ele só pega o dia de hoje se eu fiz algumas alterações que é colocando %H:%M em todos e tirando a linha de código

Comment: oq vc quer reaproveitar do mg_time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para todo o iniciante, não faça tudo em uma linha, parece legal, mas passa longe de ser

levando em conta a linha tirada do codigo, e o valor passado

```
mg_time = '2022-02-08 18:35'
mg_time = str(datetime.strptime((datetime.now()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d ') + mg_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')) + timedelta(minutes=timeframe)[11:-3]
```

separando ela em uma operação por linha

```
from datetime import *

mg_time = '2022-02-08 18:35'

mg_time2 = datetime.now()
mg_time2 = mg_time2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d ')
mg_time2 = mg_time2 + mg_time
mg_time2 = datetime.strptime(mg_time2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
mg_time2 = str(mg_time2)
mg_time2 = mg_time2 + timedelta(minutes=timeframe)[11:-3]

print(mg_time2)
```

o erro esta na soma: mg_time2 + mg_time

```
ValueError: time data '2022-03-09 2022-02-08 18:35' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
```

a mensagem de erro indica que se tem a data repetida na string passada

Comment: Sendo bem sincero eu não tenho muitas ideias para conseguir mudar esse código eu fiz diversos testes mas continuo com o mesmo erro, já que essa parte é bem importante para eu colocar um tempo determinado até outro eu coloquei no mesmo formato e acaba dando outro erro: **unconverted data remains**

Comment: Consegui mano muito obrigadoooo mesmo pela ajuda cara tu é um Deus, eu fiquei fazendo teste até que entender que a linha do código do horario tava errado a formatação